# my vscode doesn't output non ASCII characters like the ° and ₱ symbols

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

i am coding in C.
i have code runner and c extension.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("500 ₱\n");
    return 0;
}
```

this will output in the terminal: 500 Γé▒

I checked and these are my fonts in vscode text editor: Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace
I also checked and it says i am on UTF-8 on encoding in files in vscode text editor.

I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: can you make MWE ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In a Windows console CMD.EXE I change the code page with `chcp 65001` to correctly output UTF-8. It has nothing to do with the text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change encoding of your terminal. The output seems to be a correct UTF-8, but interpreted as CP437 (MS-DOS encoding). For example on Windows use in terminal command `chcp 65001` to switch to UTF-8.

U+20B1 ₱ PESO SIGN, encoded in UTF-8 becomes bytes `0xE2 0x82 0xB1`.

If you look at [CP437 chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set), `E2` is Γ, `82` is é, and `B1` is ▒. Your code is correct, just terminal is not set to UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this in a different window? That way you can rule out the code being bad.